# Kohana 3.2 'advance' ORM joins

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3

[image]

This is Database ERD that I use in application. I'm using Kohana 3.2. What I want to achieve is to generate menu for currently logged user. Each user can have many roles, so based on that user should get menu populated with modules (that are in relation with menu and user).

I have achieve this through several foreach loops. Is it possible to do this using ORM ?

*Table 'Modules' represents menu items.

Edit: this is my current code.

```
        $conf_modules = Kohana::$config->load('modules');
        $user_roles = $user->roles->find_all();

        $result     = array();
        $array  = array();

        foreach($user_roles as $user_role)
        {
            $menus   = $user_role->menus->find_all();
            $modules = $user_role->modules->find_all();
        }


        foreach($menus as $menu)
        {
            $m = $menu->modules->find_all();

            $result[]['name'] = $menu->name;

            foreach ($m as $a) 
            {
                foreach ($modules as $module) 
                {
                    if($a->name == $module->name)
                    {
                        foreach ($conf_modules as $key => $value) 
                        {
                            if($module->name == $key)
                            {
                                $array = array(
                                    'module_name' => $module->name,
                                    'text'        => $module->display_desc,
                                    'url'         => $value['url'],
                                );
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
                array_push($result, $array);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Not enough information. What kind of joins do you want?

Comment: Menu/s should be generated for user. Each menu contains modules (but only ones that belongs to user role and role menu at the same time).Thanks

Comment: Please show your "foreach loops" you want to replace with ORM joins

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be good solution.

```
        $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();

        $user_roles = $user->roles->find_all();

        $conf_modules = Kohana::$config->load('modules');

        $role_modules = ORM::factory('module')
            ->join('roles_modules')
            ->on('roles_modules.module_id','=','module.id')
            ->where('role_id','IN',$user_roles->as_array(NULL,'id'))
            ->find_all();


        $role_menus = ORM::factory('menu')
            ->join('roles_menus')
            ->on('roles_menus.menu_id','=','menu.id')
            ->where('role_id','IN',$user_roles->as_array(NULL,'id'))
            ->find_all();

        $result = array();

        foreach ($role_menus as $role_menu) 
        {
            $menu_modules = $role_menu->modules->find_all();

            if ( ! isset($result[$role_menu->name]))
                $result[$role_menu->name] = array('name' => $role_menu->name);

            foreach ($menu_modules as $menu_module) 
            {
                foreach ($role_modules as $role_module) 
                {
                    if($menu_module->name == $role_module->name)
                    {
                        foreach ($conf_modules as $key => $value) 
                        {
                            if ($key == $role_module->name)
                            {
                                $result[$role_menu->name]['modules'][]['data'] = array('name' => $role_module->display_desc, 'url' => $value['url']);
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }   
            }   
        }

        return array_values($result);
```